# mongodb on tomcat with spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, tomcat

I have written an RestAPI server that uses mongodb with spring, and successfully tested it locally. But, when I am deploying the war file on my server (tomcat) it causes an error.

After searching, I added "compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.13.3'" to my build.gradle/pom.xml file based on a tutorial. But, I don't know what to do next to solve the error. I assume it has something to do with initializing a mongodb. Here is my error on Jenkins when it tries do deploys it:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
Deploying /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AddressBook/build/libs/AddressBook.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context 
  Redeploying [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AddressBook/build/libs/AddressBook.war]
  Undeploying [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AddressBook/build/libs/AddressBook.war]
  Deploying [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AddressBook/build/libs/AddressBook.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/jenkins_home/workspace//AddressBook/build/libs/AddressBook.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/AddressBook] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    ... 18 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/AddressBook] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My application is something like https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/, with some RestAPI mappings.

And here is the tomcat log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'per
sonController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'PersonRepo'; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepositor
y': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating
 bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigu
re/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mo
ngoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependenc
yException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/sprin
gframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency e
xpressed through method 'mongoDbFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.
factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via 
factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Fai
led to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested excepti
on is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from
 class com.mongodb.Bytes
```

UPDATE (fix of above error):
So, I had this as dependency in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.13.3'
```

I changed it to (not enforcing version):

```
compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver'
```

But, now when I request a GET from my server, I see:

```
Sun Mar 04 21:05:23 UTC 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=<server_address>
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.user=<username>
```

MongoDB server on localhost:27017 (user , pwd: same as /var/jenkins_home).

Should I somehow tell my application about the path of mongoDB?
Or should I tell my application about the database name? (I think it will use some default one)

Comment: Check the logs of tomcat.

Comment: It seems you're using an incompatible version of the mongo driver. Remove the dependency to the mongo driver from the dependencies. Use the one that is automatically fetched by the spring boot mongo starter.

Comment: @JBNizet you were right, I did not enforce any versions, and it deployed successfully. However, I seems like it still cannot connect to mongodb.

Comment: It seems the mongo server is not started on your server, and thus can't accept connections.

Comment: Did you make the configurations in tomcat-users.xml file for deploying the war file in Tomcat through Jenkins ?

Comment: @TanviGarg I am able to deploy some example war file, so I guess it is configure correctly. My issue is that I am unable to access the mongodb on the same server (on another container)

Comment: @JBNizet What if mongodb is running on another container on the same server? I guess just giving the name of that server and correct port would suffice, right?

Comment: I guess you're talking about a docker container. I don't know much about that. You need to expose the mongodb port somehow I guess.